# How to use next avaible row in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to make a form that enters information into another sheet. I am unable to make each time I enter information it goes to the next row.

P.S. I need to to be able to retain what line is the next empty line.

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    Count = Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

PN = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "B").Value
Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate
Range("C2").Activate

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    If ActiveCell.Value = PN Then
        QTF = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("B2")
        Sdoc = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("B3")
        Edoc = Sdoc + 1461
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" + Count) = QTF
```

Comment: what do you mean by `retain` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I used was:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

This put my activecell on the first empty cell.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic last row for this, such as:

```
Dim LR as Long
With Sheets("NAME")
    LR = .Cells( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

The row you input is LR... Ensure that this is defined at the start of the loop, or if you are basing your loop on LR, re-define LR after the loop.

---

You use Count as your row... if you want, you could also define count as a value at the start, then iterate count at the end.

```
Count = 1
For 'Loop starts
    'Code that uses "Count"
    Count = Count + 1
Next
```